# Find limit points of $S=\{\tan(k):k=1,2,3,\cdots\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S=\{\tan(k):k=1,2,3,\cdots\}$. Find the set of limit points of $S$.

I know that by definition, $x$ is a limit point of $S$ if for any $\epsilon>0$, $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ contains some $y\ne x$. The solution says that the set of limit points is $\mathbb{R}$, but I don't see why.

First, I don't see why that for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $x = \tan(k)$ where $k\in \mathbb{N}$? Also, can't we make $\epsilon$ so small that $(\tan(1)-\epsilon,\tan(1)+\epsilon)$ contains only $\tan(1)$?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that $\pi$ is irrational. As tan is $\pi$ periodic the sequence $k$ mod $\pi$ is dense in $[0,\pi[$. So given any $x\in [0,\pi[$ you may find a subsequence so that $k_n$ mod $\pi$ converges to $x$. Then $\tan(k_n)$ converges to $\tan(x)$ and $\tan$ is surjective on ${\Bbb R}$. (If you prefer you may look at the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ instead, it's just a bit longer to write down).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\{e^{ik}: k \in \mathbb N\}$ is dense in the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

Any real number is a limit point for the $\{\tan n\}_{n\geq 1}$ sequence. Since $\pi$ is an irrational number, the sequence given by $n\pmod{\pi}$ (such a residue class has to be intended as an element of $I=(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$) is dense in $I$. The claim then follows from the fact that $\tan x$ is a continuous function over $I$, so it preserves density.

For instance, if $\frac{p_m}{q_m}$ is a convergent of the continued fraction of $\pi$, $\tan(p_m-1)\to \tan(1)$.